# Limits of integration for computing a marginal distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function, uniform-distribution

I have two functions $f_x$ = $\frac{1}{2}\delta(x-5) + 1/4$ where the 1/4 corresponds to a uniform distribution from 5 to 7. I also have $f_{y|x}$ = $\frac {1}{2}\delta(y-x-4) + 1/4$ which is 1/4 in the range of x+4 to x+6. 
I am trying to find $f_y$ using the equation:
$$
f_y = \int f_x f_{y|x} \,\mathrm dx \>.
$$ 
My question is: How do I find the limits of this integration? I had thought something like integrating from $y-4$ to $y-6$ but that doesn't really seem correct.

Comment: Deficiencies in your notation may be causing some confusion. Presumably "$\delta$" represents the point measure at zero. Don't, however, conflate constants with uniform distributions! For instance, your first "$1/4$" could more explicitly be written as $1/4 I_{[5,7]}(x)$ where $I_A$ is the indicator function for a set $A$.  (This is a guess: I presume you intend $f_x dx$ to be a probability measure.)  When you do this, *the limits of integration do not matter*: all integrals can be viewed as being over the entire Real line.

Comment: Right, sorry I'm bad about leaving out specifics sometimes. I understand that ${\bf f_x}$ is only valid between 5 and 7 and that my ${\bf f_{y|x}}$ is valid only between x+4 and x+6. I think that this would mean that my resulting answer for ${\bf f_y}$ would only be valid between 9 and 13? I'm just not totally sure how to get there.

Comment: I think confusion may arise in part due to your notation. When you write $f_{y|x}$, it reads as though you are thinking of $y$ and $x$ as separate random variables drawn from a joint distribution. However, your narrative suggests that you intend for $y$ to be a function of $x$. In this latter case, once $x$ is known, $y$ is known: the distribution of $y$ conditioned on $x$ is a single point, $y(x)$.  Which is it?

Comment: Essentially I'm talking about a calculation of total travel time. So ${\bf x}$ is guaranteed to take 5 minutes but based on a traffic light it is possible to take up to 7 minutes. ${\bf y}$ is then the total travel time, including ${\bf x}$ and a second leg of the journey which is guaranteed to take 4 additional minutes but could take up to 6 more minutes. So with ${\bf f_{y|x}}$ I am indeed talking about the conditional distribution.

Comment: So your model could be written: $x_1 \sim Unif(5,7)$, $x_2 \sim Unif(4,6)$, $y=x_1+x_2$; and your question is, What is the distribution of $y$. Is this correct?

Comment: If so, and if $x_2$ does not depend on $x_1$ in any way, then the answer's pretty obvious: $y \sim Unif(9,13)$.

Comment: Ok, yes that is correct except for the inclusion of dirac delta functions. But yes that is what I was thinking that my ${\bf f_y = \frac {1}{2} \delta(y-9) + Unif(9,13)}$. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@whuber is correct on both counts (and should be given credit for an accepted answer, imho).

In general, to derive a marginal distribution, you integrate the joint distribution over the entire support of the variable you are integrating out. In this case, integrating wrt $x$ over the entire real line gives the correct answer.

Working from first principles: recall how a conditional distribution is defined in terms of a joint distribution:

> $f(x,y) = f(y \mid x) f(x)$

The marginal distribution of $y$ is given by integrating out $x$ over its entire support (the closure of the set on which $x \ne 0$). You get the same answer if you integrate over the entire real line:

> $f(y) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) dx = \int_\mathbb{R} f(y \mid x) f(x) dx$.